# Is there a platform/forum where (phd) students can share their experiences?

Tags: phd, academic-life, supervision

Is there a platform/forum where (phd) students or post-docs can share their good or bad experiences with their supervisors?

Comment: Aside from the obvious issue that this comes dangerously close to washing one's dirty underwear in public, I think even for big labs the sample size per supervisor will be way too small for this platform to be useful.

Comment: There certainly are lots of questions here about dealing with 'bad' experiences, with supervisors or otherwise. It would not surprise me if there was a forum somewhere that specialized in it. But, what do you want out of it? Validation, solutions, just to vent?

Comment: What about ratemyprofessor?  It's not specific to this, but I would think it could include this.

Comment: @aparente001 yeah, that's one I just found yesterday ... not sure it works  also for phd/post-docs

Comment: I am also not sure about this but I don't see why one couldn't post there.

Comment: @ Jon Custer: well, (not only) my idea is to have a platform where people can share theirs experiences (and solutions).  This is motivated by the fact that there are many cases of researchers afraid to react, or they don't know how to do it. Reading stories maybe similar to yours might help (as much as people already do for cancer or similar diseases) . Of course has to be done in a way that both privacy and researcher and prof are protected, etc...

Comment: @aparente001 I am new in this community... I also don't see it too bad (or maybe I don't know enough about  'shopping questions') ... I thought this is a interesting topic, given the importance that mental health is getting in the scientific community - saying this from a global health perspective. Furthermore, in our phd student association, we are trying to measure students' mental health  through surveys and see how we can improve the support provided by the university...

Comment: jjrr, if your group wants to create such a platform, more power to you, but I don't think it would be productive for you to discuss the merits of this idea, or the nitty gritty of the design here at Academia SE.  Of course, after launching such a site, you would then be in a position to post an answer to the question you posed here.

Comment: Isn't this what [The Grad Cafe](http://forum.thegradcafe.com/) is for? That said, I'll echo what everyone else said about "this sounds like a very bad idea."